# Laravel session in middleware not always set

Tags: php, laravel, session, session-cookies

I have a middleware set on all of my web routes that saves the referer to the session if not set so I am able to log it once my visitor converts.

**This works most of the time**, meaning that sometimes the referer is one of my own pages that is often somewhere in the middle of the whole customer journey, which absolutely makes no sense to me.

So to clarify: the referer is a page where the middleware should have fired and already saved a valid or empty referer. This page is usually not the beginning or the last page before I log.

My simplified middleware:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!$request->session()->has('data')) {
        $request->session()->put('data', ['referer' => $request->header('referer')]);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: You said "My simplified middleware". What is the non-simplified version?

Comment: Is your code an API or is it an MVC application ?

Comment: @George Hanson I'm doing other stuff as well in that middleware but nothing that has to do with this issue

Comment: @Nicolas It's Laravel so MVC

Comment: Can you share your HTTP Kernel?

Comment: not clear about what is happening and what should be done. could you please elaborate?

Comment: @GeorgeHanson Do you want to know whether my middleware is defined after StartSession::class? I also included it in $middlewarePriority after StartSession

Comment: @PrateikDarji All of my pages hit the same middleware where only once per session the http referer is set. Hence, the referer should never be one of those pages affected by the middleware

Comment: what contents are there in referrer?

Comment: @PrateikDarji So it works about 90% of the time and the referer is for example the url google.com. The other 10% it is one of my own urls indicating that the referer is set halfway the visitor's session instead of upon first contact with my site.

Comment: ok can you please add code for the request where it's not getting logged, like for perticular page?